Final pressure comparison in different types of expansion processes leading from same initial state to same final volume
Say we have $4$ identical samples of an ideal gas, all at same state initially; then we are allowing them to expand to double their volumes through $4$ different processes: 
I. Isothermal irreversible 
II. Reversible such that $PV^{0.5} = \text{constant}$ 
III. Reversible adiabatic 
IV. Irreversible adiabatic expansion against constant external pressure.
Now there was a $PV$ diagram in this question, with the initial point marked, and $4$ points lying on the same vertical line (same final volume), stating that those are the end points for the processes named above.
We were asked to match which process belongs to which point, which in other words is asking us to compare final pressures in all of those $4$ processes.
My teacher said that the answer was II > I > IV > III (order of final pressures).
I can understand why II > I > III and IV > III.
But how do we compare the process IV's final pressure with process I and II?
Am I supposed to assume that the difference in final pressures of reversible adiabatic and irreversible adiabatic expansions is just small on this comparison scale?
Note: This was in a high school thermodynamics class, so my knowledge is limited to that level.


Could you add a diagram to your question? (e.g., take a screenshot or a photo). Note that  #4 is under constant external pressure - it is easy to guess what the diagram should look like for this one.

@Roger V. Added it, but the numbering in it is a bit different so I thing that would cause confusion to a reader.

Edited the numbering style.

Let's compare only 1 and 4, since all the other inequalities follow.
I hope I'll be able to provide an answer easy to understand by a high-school student, since there is no need for complex mathematical tools here or physical concepts. Anyway, let me know.
Here I'll use only:

the equations of state of ideal gas
$$P V= n R T \qquad , \qquad E = C_V T \quad , \quad\text{ with constant $C_V$} \ ,$$

the first principle of thermodynamics, namely the total energy balance for a closed system,
$$\Delta E^{tot} = \Delta L^{ext} + \Delta Q^{ext} \ ,$$
being $E^{tot}$ the total energy of the system, and $\Delta L^{ext}$ and $\Delta Q^{ext}$ the work done by the environment on the system and the heat exchanged with it. Total energy is the sum of the kinetic energy $K$ and the internal energy $E$,


$$E^{tot} = E + K \ .$$
1. Isothermal irreversible. Without knowing anything about the transformation, if it's isothermal, $T^{fin} = T^{ini}$ is constant, and thus the equation of state of the ideal gas provides,
$$P^{fin}_1 = P^{ini} \frac{V^{ini}}{V^{fin}} \ .$$
4. Adiabatic irreversible. Adiabatic transformation involves no heat flux $\Delta Q^{ext} = 0$. If $\Delta K = 0$, $\Delta E^{tot} = \Delta E$
$$\Delta E = \Delta L^{ext} = - P^{ext} \Delta V = - P^{ext} (V^{fin} - V^{ini}) < 0 \ .$$
The variation of internal energy can be written as,
$$\Delta E = C_V \Delta T =  \frac{C_V}{nR}\left( P^{fin} V^{fin} - P^{ini} V^{ini} \right)$$
and putting everything together,
$$P^{fin} V^{fin} - P^{ini} V^{ini} = - \frac{n R}{C_V} P^{ext} \Delta V $$
or
$$P^{fin}_4 = \underbrace{P^{ini} \frac{V^{ini}}{V^{fin}}}_{= P^{fin}_1} - \underbrace{\frac{n R}{C_V V^{fin}} P^{ext} \Delta V}_{>0} \lt P^{fin}_1 \ . $$

I think in the last step, in RHS's 2nd term Vfin needs to be in denominator. But yes, I got my answer, thank you very much.

Yeah you're right. Forgot it and edited now
